# Without jQuery, how could I selectively remove elements that exist in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm just getting started with Javascript for about a week now, after creating a few Tampermonkey scripts.

The page I'm working on has dynamic elements that basically pop up at random with each page load.  For example, sometimes the page will only have a "here" element loaded, and on a different page load, I might see only "what" and "doing" loaded instead. On each page load, I'm hoping to have my script scan for all of these elements, and remove any that have loaded.

Thankfully, their selector paths are easy to find, but I'm looking to find a better looking / easier way to have my script find any of these 5 elements. Here's the layout that's been working:

```
var what = document.querySelector('#wrapper > footer > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > span')
var am = document.querySelector('#wrapper > footer > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > span')
var i = document.querySelector('#wrapper > footer > div > div > div:nth-child(36) > span')
var doing = document.querySelector('#wrapper > footer > div > div > div:nth-child(4) > span')
var here = document.querySelector('#wrapper > footer > div > div > div:nth-child(5) > span')

if (what) {
    what.remove();
}
if (am) {
    am.remove();
}
if (i) {
    i.remove();
}
if (doing) {
    doing.remove();
}
if (here) {
    here.remove();
}
```

Having a TON of IF statements will work of course, and I've got a strong feeling that adding all my vars into an array would be the cleanest method, but after looking into arrays and array statements so far, I don't quite yet know what would be my best option.

Ideally, I'm trying to aim for something like:

```
var group = [what, am, i, doing, here]
if (group.includes == true)
true.remove();
```

..or something like that. Is there a much better way to do this than my current method with using a flood of IF statements?

Comment: You're on right track, build array form as you did for `group` and than loop through it using `forEach` and remove the element as per your conditions

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I had looked up ```forEach``` a few times, but wasn't quite sure how I could incorporate it into the script exactly.  Some answers were given here that showed how to use that parameter though, and it all makes so much sense now. I may just have to go back and try a few other parameters and toy around with the results through console now that I've a better idea.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there - just loop through `group` with `forEach` and `remove` each item if it exists:

```
var what = document.querySelector('#wrapper > footer > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > span')
var am = document.querySelector('#wrapper > footer > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > span')
var i = document.querySelector('#wrapper > footer > div > div > div:nth-child(36) > span')
var doing = document.querySelector('#wrapper > footer > div > div > div:nth-child(4) > span')
var here = document.querySelector('#wrapper > footer > div > div > div:nth-child(5) > span')

var group = [what, am, i, doing, here];

group.forEach(item => {
    if (item) item.remove();
});
```

Comment: Aha there it is! Ahhh, thanks so much for filling in the missing piece there. ```forEach``` kept popping out after digging through array parameters, but I wasn't sure how I could fully utilize it.  I think at one point I was going as far as somehow trying to use ```splice()``` to sort all the loaded elements into a completely new array, and then find a way to delete only those elements in that new array, haha.  I just about lost my insanity after going at this until 4 AM. Thanks for the super quick and helpful answer!